# iOS: Share login between App and Website via iCloud Keychain

Tags: ios, icloud, keychain

Is it possible to register / login on a website and store the credentials in iCloud Keychain and then if you open the native iOS App the login form is filled out with the credentials from the website?

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/shared_web_credentials

Answer (score 0):

This WWDC session is a great way to start: [WWDC 2017 - Introducing Password AutoFill for Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/206)